# variable within functions-Linux Shell Script

Tags: linux, function, shell, variables

i am facing an issue with this simple code , where i call a function , but the variable $X of that function doesnt seem to pass outside, since the printout message is always "Your interface is ." ... 
Am i missing something?

```
#! /bin/bash
function choose
{
echo -e " Choose your interface:"
echo -e " 1) WLan0"
echo -e " 2) WLan0mon"
echo -e " Choose: "
read -e X
if [ "$X" = "1" ]
then
    X="wlan0"
elif [ "$X" = "2" ]
then
    X="wlan0mon"
fi
}


(choose)
echo -e "Your interface is $X."
```

Comment: I think `X` only exists inside the scope of your `choose` function. Try either removing the function definition/call altogether, or moving the `echo` inside the body of the `choose` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `(choose)` using the parentheses executes it in a subshell.

From [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/subshells.html):

> Variables in a subshell are not visible outside the block of code in the subshell. They are not accessible to the parent process, to the shell that launched the subshell. These are, in effect, local variables.

Removing the parentheses around `choose` will make variable `X` visible to your `echo`.